# Windows socket.Send data isn't received until socket.Close

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, send

I'm developing a server application that asynchronously accepts TCP connections (BeginAccept/EndAccept) and data (BeginReceive/EndReceive). The protocol requires an ACK to be sent whenever the EOM character is found before it will send the next message. The accept and receive are working but the sending app is not receiving the ACK (sent synchronously).

```
    private void _receiveTransfer(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        SocketState state = result.AsyncState as SocketState;
        int bytesReceived = state.Socket.EndReceive(result);

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            state.Socket.Close();
            return;
        }

        state.Offset += bytesReceived;
        state.Stream.Write(state.Buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

        if (state.Buffer[bytesReceived - 1] == 13)
        {
            // process message
            Messages.IMessage message = null;
            try
            {
                var value = state.Stream.ToArray();

                // do some work
                var completed = true;

                if (completed)
                {
                    // send positive ACK
                    var ackMessage = string.Format(ack, message.TimeStamp.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"), message.MessageType, message.Id, "AA", message.Id);
                    var buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ackMessage);
                    int bytesSent = state.Socket.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    // send rejected ACK
                    var ackMessage = string.Format(ack, message.TimeStamp.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"), message.MessageType, message.Id, "AR", message.Id);
                    state.Socket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ackMessage));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // log exception


                // send error ACK
                if (message != null)
                {
                    var ackMessage = string.Format(ack, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"), message.MessageType, message.Id, "AE", message.Id);
                    state.Socket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ackMessage));
                }
            }
        }

        state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(_receiveTransfer), state);
    }
```

The state.Socket.Send returns the correct number of bytes but the data isn't received until the socket is disposed.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a `Flush` function?  I'd guess the socket data is being buffered, awaiting more data...

Comment: The string.Format() call looks strange.  But I suspect the real problem is on the other end of the wire.

Answer (score 2):

- you shouldn't do anything synchronous from async completion routines. Under load you can end up hijacking all IO completion threads from the thread pool and severly hurt performance, up to and including complete IO deadlock. So don't send ACKs synchronously from async callback.
- protocols and formats that use preambles are easier to manage that those that use terminators. Ie. write the length of the message in the fixed size message header as opposed to detecting a terminator \0x13. Of course, this applies if the protocol is under your control to start with.

As for your question, you didn't specify if the same code as you posted is also on the client side too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the protocol and the client is a verification app for testing protocol compliance.

Comment: do you set any socket option when creating it, like SO_SNDBUF? Can you see the ACK bytes being sent, using a network monitor like http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en ?

Answer (score 0):

How long are you giving it?  The network stack can buffer, and that could delay transmition.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a.aspx):

> To increase network efficiency, the
>   underlying system may delay
>   transmission until a significant
>   amount of outgoing data is collected.
>   A successful completion of the Send
>   method means that the underlying
>   system has had room to buffer your
>   data for a network send.

You might want to try flushing using the [IOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.iocontrol.aspx) method.

**edit**

Actually, the IOControl flush will kill the buffer.  You may want to check out the [Two Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem) to see if your protocol will have some inherent problems.

Answer (score 0):

try setting TCP_NODELAY socket option

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `NoDelay` property on the socket to `true`?  When set to `false` (the default), data is buffered for up to 200 milliseconds before it's sent.  The reason is to reduce network traffic by limiting the number of packets that are sent.  Setting `NoDelay` to `true` will force the data to be sent sooner.

Comment: This still happens on some adapters that have Adaptive Interrupts set. Such as Intel.